# How far exactly does my frightened character have to run?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

My character has failed a Will Save. He's Frightened for 6 rounds. That means that he

> flees from the source of its fear as best it can... [and] can use special abilities, including spells, to flee; indeed, the creature must use such means if they are the only way to escape.

Straightforward enough. I've got to run away. So, I double move away from the action on my turn. But the party is fighting in a complicated building with lots of rooms and corridors, and the rest of the party is engaged with, and obstructing my foes from pursuing me. Do I need to keep running, in any direction that's away (or even a random one, as one GM who I'm almost certain was wrong insisted) until the fear effect ends? Or If the object of my fear is out of sight, and I'm confident it can't reach or harm me, can I stay put? What if I ready an action to continue running as soon as the opponent comes into sight?

If I can't stop running... well, a 5 round fear is going to leave me *very* far away from the rest of the party.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## You run until you are out of sight/hearing of the source

This is one of the rare instances where **d20pfsrd is wrong**
<sup>*</sup>, as their text for the frightened condition differs from that on the [paizo PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#fear), which is identical to the text presented in the Core Rulebook, 5th printing, page 563 (This is also unaffected by any of the official Errata from 1st to 6th printing):

> **Frightened:** Characters who are frightened are shaken, and in addition they flee from the source of their fear as quickly as they can. They can choose the paths of their flight. Other than that stipulation, **once they are out of sight (or hearing) of the source of their fear, they can act as they want**. If the duration of their fear continues, however, characters can be forced to flee if the source of their fear presents itself again. Characters unable to flee can fight (though they are still shaken).

(emphasis mine). The bold part is present for panicked, as well. Take note that the condition timer is still running, and you immediately start running again if you see/hear the source of your fear as long as the fear effect itself is active.

<sup>* In fact, the text on d20pfsrd is taken directly from [d20srd](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm).</sup>

Comment: I want to note here that the d20pfsrd text isn't actually erroneous, except by omission--it displays what the Paizo PRD displays in the same section, on Conditions (compare [here](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#frightened) to [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Frightened)). It's just that the pfsrd omits the Fear glossary heading that would clarify the condition subheadings.